# Project and build structure for Microsoft DirectShow based virtual webcam application on Window 10

Tags: video, com, video-capture, directshow, windows-10-desktop

I am trying to create simplest virtual webcam application which can display image file on my local filesystem.

After initial research on [stackoverflow links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=directshow%20virtual%20webcam) and seeing [OBS Studio source code](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/tree/master/plugins/win-dshow) I got some idea how can I achieve this.

1. I would need to use [Microsoft DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow).
2. I would need to develop one source filter that would work as capture filter using [IBaseFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nn-strmif-ibasefilter)
3. I would need to develop another source filter that would work as output filter or virtual webcam filter. I would need to compile this filter as [.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library) file and will need to register using `regsvr32.exe`
   As given on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/building-directshow-filters
4. I would need to create [Filter Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/the-filter-graph-and-its-components) and [Capture Filter Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/about-the-capture-graph-builder) using `CoCreateInstance` like

   `hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFilterGraph, (void **)&graph);`

   `hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void **)&builder);`
5. Then I would need to add these filters to `Filter Graph`
6. Then I would set `Filter Graph` to `Capture Filter Graph` like `hr = builder->SetFiltergraph(graph);`

Here is my confusion now:
After these steps I am not sure if I have to wrap these `Graph Filters` and `Capture Graph Filter` in one application which would be having `main` method and compile it to get .exe file or I need to compile as another .dll file.

Or How should I wrap these steps to create final application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481713/how-to-get-started-with-directshow/3483072#3483072

Comment: The question lacks integrity. The title says you want virtual webcam. This assumes you need your code to implement a camera which does not exist physically ("virtual"). In the body of the question you are trying to do unrelated things: display video, create an application etc.

Comment: I think he just wants to capture from webcam.

Comment: @RomanR.: Yes I want to create simplest virtual webcam application which can output any image or video to virtual camera. That virtual camera should be visible as video device in online meetings like Google meet or zoom. So I assumed that I need to create two filters to achieve this. one for virtual camera and other for passing images or videos frame to that virtual camera.

Comment: @user123: No I want to create virtual webcam which would be displaying image or video from local file

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I can't really help here. Anyway you should definitely use MediaFoundation. I've been trying to go with DirectShow for several projects and when I found out about MediaFoundation, I realised how much I was wrong to work with such an outdated library (DirectShow).

Comment: @user123: I guess currently MediaFoundation is not mature enough to give all capabilities of DirectShow. Can we create Virtual webcam using MediaFoundation?

Comment: It is definitely mature enough! It is the recommended library to use in advanced C++ WinAPI applications. It is recommended by Microsoft and has been for a long time. It is an iteration of DirectShow. It is not a downgrade from DirectShow.

Comment: @user123: I would love to use MediaFoundation but I am not sure if I can create virtual camera device using MediaFoundation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create simplest virtual webcam application which can output any image or video to virtual camera. That virtual camera should be visible as video device in online meetings like Google meet or zoom.

There is no support for virtual web cameras in Windows as a unified API and what you are trying to achieve is, generally speaking, possible but far more complicated than a question of setup.

The task can be decomposed into three parts, and you will be able to find past StackOverflow questions that elaborate all of the three (some references are given below).

**First**, you need to resolve the problem of integration of a virtual camera into third party software. Per the statement I started from, the OS API offers no way for a generic virtual camera interface in terms of OS extensibility point that enables third party application "see" a new camera device.

A popular way to inject a fake camera device into applications is virtual DirectShow video source (and respectively [Vivek's VCam](https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam) source code).

The diagram from [Registering a network video stream as a virtual camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097485/868014) describes the APIs used by applications to work with cameras and illustrates limitations of virtual DirectShow cameras, specifically why they are not visible by every video-enabled application in Windows.

See also questions [Virtual Driver Cam not recognized by browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923351/868014) and [DirectShow filter is not shown as input capture device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49222397/868014).

All in all, to develop a virtual webcam for all and any application in Windows you would need to develop a driver, something few are ready to deal with.

Newer Media Foundation API offers nothing to help with functionality of virtual webcam.

**Second**, you need to define a method of injection of video frames into whatever virtual camera you develop. There is no need to use DirectShow or Media Foundation because in the end of the day all you need is to submit video frames to the back end of your virtual camera implementation and you are free to use any convenient method.

Use of DirectShow for this task make sense overall, but you don't need to. If you are not familiar with the API and you are starting with basics of creation of a filter graph, then it is quite likely that it is easier to go with a non-DirectShow solution. If you need to mix a real webcam image into your feed, you can capture it with Media Foundation in particular. If you plan to use GPU services of sorts, Media Foundation would be a better API to use again. DirectShow still remains good option as API to build your pipeline on.

**Third**, there is often a question of interprocess communication to connect the virtual camera implementation and the source of the video. In some cases it is not necessary, but more often it is just overlooked.

A virtual DirectShow camera (or virtual Media Foundation camera if you, for example, will be detouring) is running in context of camera consuming process, and cameras in general might be accessed from multiple applications including simultaneously. Quite so often you expect to produce video from another [single] application, including the case of application of unlatching bitness/architecture, so you are to take care of the challenge of passing data between the processes. If you are in an attempt to develop a driver for virtual camera you will have the same task too.

I mentioned aspects of this in MSDN question there: [How to implement a "source filter" for splitting camera video based on Vivek's vcam?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce717600-750b-46c0-8a63-31d65659740b/how-to-implement-a-source-filter-for-splitting-camera-video-based-on-viveks-vcam?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment), then there [Read USB camera's input edit and send the output to a virtual camera on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017155/868014) and also there [How to create Directshow filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17314710/868014).

All in all, it is not a question of project setup. Instead, it is a set of quite sophisticated problems to solve (which are doable though, and we see examples of this).

---

For virtual cameras in Windows 11, see also footnote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935646/868014).

Comment: Thanks for giving your thoughts so nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference: Starting with Windows 11 there is a dedicated API for virtual webcams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfvirtualcamera/nf-mfvirtualcamera-mfcreatevirtualcamera

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow is outdated. You should be using Microsoft MediaFoundation instead. It is well documented and it works well. The following code will work to capture from webcam:

```
void Webcam::StartRecording()
{
    HRESULT hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pConfig, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        std::cout << "Failed to create attribute store";
    }

    hr = pConfig->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        std::cout << "Failed to request capture devices";
    }

    hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pConfig, &ppDevices, &count);
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        std::cout << "Failed to enumerate capture devices";
    }

    hr = ppDevices[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSource));
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        std::cout << "Failed to connect camera to source";
    }

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(pSource, pConfig, &pReader);
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        std::cout << "Failed to create source reader";
    }

    IMFMediaType* pType = NULL;
    DWORD dwMediaTypeIndex = 0;
    DWORD dwStreamIndex = 0;
    hr = pReader->GetNativeMediaType(dwStreamIndex, dwMediaTypeIndex, &pType);
    LPVOID representation;
    pType->GetRepresentation(AM_MEDIA_TYPE_REPRESENTATION, &representation);
    GUID subType = ((AM_MEDIA_TYPE*)representation)->subtype;
    BYTE* pbFormat = ((AM_MEDIA_TYPE*)representation)->pbFormat;
    GUID formatType = ((AM_MEDIA_TYPE*)representation)->formattype;
    if (subType == MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2) { std::cout << 1; };
    RECT rect;
    if (formatType == FORMAT_DvInfo) { std::cout << 1; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_MPEG2Video) { std::cout << 2; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_MPEGStreams) { std::cout << 3; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_MPEGVideo) { std::cout << 4; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_None) { std::cout << 5; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_VideoInfo) { std::cout << 6; }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_VideoInfo2){
        rect = ((VIDEOINFOHEADER2*)pbFormat)->rcSource;
    }
    if (formatType == FORMAT_WaveFormatEx) { std::cout << 8; }
    if (formatType == GUID_NULL) { std::cout << 9; }

    int videoWidth = ((VIDEOINFOHEADER2*)pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biWidth;
    int videoHeight = ((VIDEOINFOHEADER2*)pbFormat)->bmiHeader.biHeight;

    IsRecording = true;
    DWORD streamIndex, flags;
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp;
    IMFSample* pSample;

    while (IsRecording){
        hr = pReader->ReadSample(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, &streamIndex, &flags, &llTimeStamp, &pSample);
        if (FAILED(hr)){
            std::cout << "Failed to get image from camera";
        }
        if (pSample != NULL){
            IMFMediaBuffer* pBuffer;
            pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
            unsigned char* data;
            DWORD length;
            pBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&length);
            HRESULT hr = pBuffer->Lock(&data, NULL, &length);
            if (FAILED(hr)){
                std::cout << "Failed to get data from buffer";
            }

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 640, 480);
            BITMAPINFOHEADER header = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 640, 480, 1, 24, BI_RGB, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
            BITMAPINFO info = { header, NULL };
            SetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, 480, &rgb[0], &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

            HIMAGELIST imageList = ImageList_Create(640, 480, ILC_COLOR24, 1, 500);
            if (bitmap != NULL) {
                ImageList_Add(imageList, bitmap, NULL);
                BOOL drawn = ImageList_Draw(imageList, 0, hdc, 0, 0, ILD_IMAGE);
                
                DeleteObject(bitmap);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Failed to create bitmap" << std::endl;
            }
            ImageList_Destroy(imageList);
            DeleteObject(hdc);
            pBuffer->Unlock();
            pBuffer->Release();
            pSample->Release();
        }
    }
    pSource->Stop();
    pSource = NULL;
    MFShutdown();
}
```

You may need to convert the data buffer to a RGB format before you send it to an image_list. Most modern cameras output in RGB but my older webcam on my laptop outputs YUY2. If you need to convert from YUY2 to RGB, feel free to ask. There probably is better code to do the same but this code works well. It leaves you in control of the image. You probably could show the image in a static control instead. image_list leaves you in control to add several images and resize them at will.

Comment: I dont want to capture from webcam. I want to create virtual webcam